Are there any kissing laws in the United States?
My question is this: are there any laws banning or regulating kissing? I looked up the obscenity laws in the United States, and it seems like kissing (without nudity) is not considered obscene. But perhaps there's other laws regarding kissing? Do anyone know of any such laws? I'll appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!
Note that the situation I'm talking about is kissing with both persons' consent, so I'm not looking for sexual assault laws.

Can you be more specific?  Kissing a person against their will would be assault (likely sexual assault depending on the circumstances) but it isn't clear if that is the sort of law you're referencing.

@JustinCave No, I meant a situation where both sides consent to kissing. Sorry for the confusion. I'll edit my post to reflect this. Thanks for pointing out.

Further to @JustinCave's comment, there are laws governing other sorts of behavior that could be violated by kissing even if the law doesn't mention kissing specifically, for example laws concerning public disturbances, for example, "without lawful authority, [disturbing] any lawful assembly or
meeting of persons" (NY Penal Law 240.20(4)).

"so I'm not looking for sexual assault laws." Can we further assume both parties are over any applicable age of consent (to eliminate any child protection laws)?

@phoog I can imagine some people finding kissing distasteful in some contexts, but I find it hard to believe it would raise to the level of being a public disturbance.

@TripeHound Those would probably be sexual assault against the child.

@TripeHound Yeah, we can eliminate the case of one party underage while the other is over the age of majority. However, I intend to include cases where the two parties are both underage, for example two 16 year old's. I do not think that'll trigger any child protection laws, though.

@phoog I think public disturbances are another matter, I do not see the direct relationship between that and kissing. I meant kissing and kissing only, without the violation of other laws.

Any comment from downvoters? Why is this such a bad question? I thought I clarified everything. Please state where I can improve.

Pretty sure it'd also violate regular assault laws if it's non-consensual. Try kissing a police officer while they're on duty and you'll probably be arrested for assaulting a law enforcement officer, just like you would for spitting on them.

virginia
Certain kinds of romantic kissing between adults and preteen children is a crime, even if the child apparently consents. No sexual contact is required for the commission of this offense.

§ 18.2-370.6. Penetration of mouth of child with lascivious intent
Any person 18 years of age or older who, with lascivious intent, kisses a child under the age of 13 on the mouth while knowingly and intentionally penetrating the mouth of such child with his tongue is guilty of a Class 1 misdemeanor.

The story behind this law was that there was actually someone who did this prior to the law's passage and the legislature wanted to ensure that anyone who tried such a thing in the future would have to register as a sex offender.

OP clarified (albeit only in a comment) that they are not interested in adult/child situations.
